# SFTP Fastput not uploading the file contents

Tags: node.js

I am reading the file contents from directory and uploading via SFTP. For some reason, the files are not getting uploaded with no errors throwing. I cannot debug why files does not show up in FTP.

Any thoughts how to debug the issue ?

I tried with SFTP.put && SFTP.Fastput methods but no luck

```
const fs = require('fs');

var Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
var sftp = new Client();

const filePath = "/Users/NodeJSWorkspace/helloworld/cvs/";

var fileNames = [];
fs.readdirSync(filePath).forEach(file => {
console.log(file);
fileNames.push(file);
});

sftp.connect({
host: '10.7.10.10',
port: '22',
username: 'test',
password: 'test',
}).then(() => {
  return sftp.list(filePath); 
}).then((data) => {

console.log("Length :",fileNames.length);
for(let i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
    let filename = fileNames[i];
    let remoteFilename = '/ftp/' + filename;
    let localFilename = filePath + filename;


    sftp.fastPut(localFilename,remoteFilename,function(err) {
        if (err)
           console.log("ERR ******: " + err);
        });

  }
  sftp.end();
 }).catch((err) => {
 console.log(err, 'catch error');
 sftp.end();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is in your last "then" callback function, where you have a "for" loop in which you call "sftp.fastPut", but immediately after that the loop, you call "sftp.end()". The calls to "sftp.fastPut" are asynchronous, and normally "end" or "close" will cancel all pending asynchronous operations without necessarily triggering the error callback. You'll need to use a promise chain or some other asynchronous pattern.

Note that I haven't used "ssh2-sftp-client" before, so I'm not 100% sure. I'm basing my answer on experience with similar Node modules.

Comment: It worked. thanks. Can you share snippets on this ?  "You'll need to use a promise chain or some other asynchronous pattern."